# How to set trailing stop loss in Tradingview Pine Script v4 strategy?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, pine-script

I'm looking for a solution to set a trailing stop loss inside a strategy script in TradingView's Pine Script version 4 language

Docs provided with the platform does not seem to work

Ideally I'd like to compute trailing stop level when a position is open, plot this level and monitor if price falls below that level

Unfortunately they changed variable saving method and most of docs for older version does not work anymore

Any help?

Comment: Always try to add code, so that somebody could answer.